# does all attribute in composite key have unique values

Tags: composite-primary-key

if a composite key is built by 2 attributes empname,empid of type VARCHAR and NUMBER respectively.then is it true that both these attributes are unique and not null.pls expalin

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from trying this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of a composite primary key can be duplicates.

A composite primary key as a whole must be unique.